# find polygon coordinate on oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, geospatial, spatial, oracle-spatial

I have a one big polygon name is 0204 and after I split it two small 1003 and 1004, when I can find 1 and 2 points coordinates see photo

[image: screenshot]

and geometry here 
-- 0204 --
`MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 2400000, null, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(8464488.62343735992908477783203125, 4444319.428492070175707340240478515625, 8464488.781260209158062934875488281250, 4444284.2415307201445102691650390625, 8464503.001509850844740867614746093750, 4444284.1077903099358081817626953125, 8464502.7877615205943584442138671875, 4444319.36063767969608306884765625, 8464488.62343735992908477783203125, 4444319.428492070175707340240478515625))`

--1003--
`MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 2400000, null, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(8464488.695278989151120185852050781250, 4444303.411238789558410644531250, 8464488.781260209158062934875488281250, 4444284.2415307201445102691650390625, 8464503.001509850844740867614746093750, 4444284.1077903099358081817626953125, 8464502.874620059505105018615722656250, 4444305.03532961010932922363281250, 8464488.695278989151120185852050781250, 4444303.411238789558410644531250))`

--1004--
`MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 2400000, null, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1003, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(8464488.62343735992908477783203125, 4444319.428492070175707340240478515625, 8464488.695278989151120185852050781250, 4444303.411238789558410644531250, 8464502.874620059505105018615722656250, 4444305.03532961010932922363281250, 8464502.7877615205943584442138671875, 4444319.36063767969608306884765625, 8464488.62343735992908477783203125, 4444319.428492070175707340240478515625))`

if you can write query thank you advance

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This is not a free coding service.  Please read [ask].  What have you attempted.   Showing no effort on your part is not going to get much response.

Answer (score 0):

Points 1 and 2 are

```
(8464488.62343735992908477783203125, 4444319.428492070175707340240478515625)
(8464488.695278989151120185852050781250, 4444303.411238789558410644531250).
```

Solution is left as an exercise for the reader.